# Does power bi mobile app not support viewing power bi reports published to the power bi report server?

Tags: powerbi, power-bi-report-server

I'm using Power bi report server. I'm exploring the mobile app based access and came across the following link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/consumer/mobile/mobile-apps-offline-data#considerations-and-limitations

> In the Power BI mobile apps, you can't see Power BI Desktop (.pbix)
> files saved to Power BI Report Server.

Does power bi mobile app not support viewing power bi reports published to the power bi report server?

Comment: This is when you're offline...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation says it only when it's offline. If you are online you can view your reports in the mobile app.

Link on How to connect Report server and Mobile apps -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/consumer/mobile/mobile-app-ssrs-kpis-mobile-on-premises-reports

Answer (score 0):

There is no such restriction. You can connect to on on premises reports server and view these files